# Passing a JSON object to servlet from android

Tags: java, android, json, servlets

I am uploading a file to server from my android application using the below code, and its working fine. now I want to pass a jsonobject also to servlet, I tried some way like

```
    mpEntity.addPart("param",new StringBody(details.toString(),"text/plain",
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

here the details is  a JSON object, but its not working, so please help me to solve this.

this is my  code(in android) for file uploading.

```
           private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("m1", "adad");

        obj.put("m2", "adadad");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://172.20.56.229:8084/AndroidTesting/UploadServlet");

        File file = new File("/sdcard/CEA.txt");

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFe = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFe);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out
                .println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but its not working": can you be a bit more specific here? What happens? Any error messages or exceptions, ...?

Comment: @Henry The thing is there is no error , file is getting uploaded in to the specific folder. and I am trying to print that json object.. but it's printing "" value. this is my problem

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Is there something wrong on the client or on the server side? Can you debug the servlet? What does it receive in the request?